# how to change up arrow (green color) or down arrow (red color) or a dash (black color) in the flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a the following sample code for flexdashbard in R:

````
---
title: "My Dashboard"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r init, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
gc()

```


```{r setup1, include = FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(thematic)
library(ggplot2)
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)

```


Home {data-icon="fa-home" .main}
=====================================   

```{r, include=FALSE}

theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 20))

```


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Heading 1

```{r}
valueBox(1, icon = "fa-pencil", color="success")
```

### Heading 2

```{r}

valueBox(2, icon = "fa-file-text-o", color="info")

```

### Heading 3

```{r}
valueBox(3, icon = "fa-database", color = "danger")
```

Row
-------------------------------------------



Screen 2 {data-icon="fa-signal"}
==========================================================================

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=350}
-------------------------------------

<h3>Selection Area</h3>

```{r}

hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;")

sliderInput("contact_rate", "Set contact rate", value = 91, min = 0, max = 100)

hr()

numericInput(inputId="my_input", "Enter a number:", 4, min = 0)

actionButton("submit", "Submit")


```


Value Boxes 
-------------------------------------

### Primary

```{r}

observeEvent(input$submit, {
  arrow_icon_temp <- ifelse(input$my_input > 3, icon("fa-arrow-up", class = "text-success"), 
                            icon("fa-arrow-down", class = "text-danger"))
  output$arrow <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      input$my_input, caption = "Days", 
      color = "white",
      icon = arrow_icon_temp
    )
  })
})


renderValueBox({
  valueBoxOutput("arrow")
})

```

### Info

```{r}

valueBox(2, caption = "Weeks", color = "red", icon = "fa-chart-line")

```

### Success

```{r}

valueBox(3, caption = "Weeks", color = "green", icon = "fa-chart-line")

```



Gauges 
-------------------------------------

### Success Rate

```{r}

renderGauge({
  gauge(input$contact_rate, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', 
        sectors = gaugeSectors( danger = c(0, 20), warning = c(20, 80), success = c(80, 100)))
  })

```

### Warning metric

```{r}

renderGauge({
  gauge(input$contact_rate, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', 
        sectors = gaugeSectors( danger = c(0, 20), warning = c(20, 80), success = c(80, 100)))
  })

```

### Danger!

```{r}

renderGauge({
  gauge(input$contact_rate, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', 
        sectors = gaugeSectors( danger = c(0, 20), warning = c(20, 80), success = c(80, 100)))
  })


```
````

and the dashboard looks like that:

[image]

I am trying to change up arrow (green color) or down arrow (red color) or a dash (black color) in the frist valueBox reactively, meaning, when i provide a number in the NumericInput (in side bar), and then click on submit button, then ONLY should be the change in valueBox be reflected along with up or down arrow icon (as shown in the picture) basis the condition applied in the above code.

But then I am encountering two issues here:

1. first time, when i launch the dashboart (run the app), I need to provide the input number and then click on Submit button, then only valueBox shows the number I just had input.
2. but, second time the moment i change the number, the number is displayed on the valueBoax immediately even without clicking on Submit button, this should not be the case.
3. arrow (red, down or green, up) is still not getting displayed

What am I doing wrong here? any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, to format the style of your `icons` you need to save this chunk of `css` in a ***styles.css*** file inside your ***www*** folder:

```
     .value-box .icon i.fa.fa-arrow-up{
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 15px;
      font-size: 80px;
      color: rgba(0, 153, 0);
    }
    
    .value-box .icon i.fa.fa-arrow-down{
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 15px;
      font-size: 80px;
      color: rgba(255, 0, 0);
    }
```

2. Remember to include this file in the yaml:

```
---
title: "My Dashboard"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
always_allow_html: yes
css: www/styles.css 
---
```

3. You need to break the dependency that your `renderValueBox` takes on `input$my_input`, because you need to `renderValueBox` only when `input$submit` is clicked. `isolate` is the function for that: it suspend the reactive actions of the input or reactive object inside and is only evaluated when another input or reactive object linked to it's enviroment is changed. So with some modifications, your chunk is now like this:

````
### Primary

```{r}

observeEvent(input$submit, {
  
  output$arrow <- renderValueBox({
    
    valueBox(
      ifelse(input$submit == 0, "Select number of days", isolate(input$my_input)), caption = "Days", 
      color = "white",
      icon = ifelse(isolate(input$my_input) > 3, "fa-arrow-up", "fa-arrow-down"))
    
  })
}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


renderValueBox({
  valueBoxOutput("arrow")
})
````

**EDIT:** answering *can I also include a text box like "Error: " in between the number displayed and the arrow?*

That would mean to change the `value` argument in `valueBox` to a `shiny::tagList` that includes the needed elements. Those elements need to be in the same row; in different columns. Now your `valueBox` looks like this:

```
valueBox(
      value = tagList(tags$div(class = "parent",
                       tags$div(class = "column", ifelse(input$submit == 0, "Select number of days", isolate(input$my_input))),
                       tags$div(class = "column", tags$h5("Error:")))), 
      caption = "Days", 
      color = "white",
      icon = ifelse(isolate(input$my_input) > 3, "fa-arrow-up", "fa-arrow-down"))
```

And your ***styles.css*** file needs to include this lines:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}
```

Comment: this is awesome! very precise. Just one more thing: like `caption` within `valueBox`, can I also include a text box like "Error: " in between the number displayed and the arrow? what tweaking will be needed?

Comment: Added answer, please check it out!

Comment: awesome!... i have given prize to you for such a nice explanation and also giving me an idea how to tweak the codes for other purposes. One last thing, I would be happy if I could see that `fa-arrows-left-right` kind of icon is also available in shiny, i tried but it did not work .. I also tried `fa-dash` (wanted to use for the condition where `input$my_input == 3`) but it did not work either... :'(

Comment: great! see https://fontawesome.com/search?q=arrow&o=r&m=free for name of icons available. The names there must include "fa-" as prefix. I tried `fa-arrow-left`, `fa-arrow-right` and `fa-minus` and they all worked.